# Generating PDF of a Web Page with Phantom

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am developing in Node an application where I have an html page, which I fill in with bank data and then I need to save this page in PDF. I'm trying to use Phatom, I already know several tutorials, but when I pass the URL of the page it saves again and again, it does not end the process and always gets overwriting the generated PDF. What can I do to resolve this?

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1024 });

    const status = await page.open('http://localhost/gerar_diploma?id_aluno='+_id);

    console.time('wait');

    await timeout(500);

    console.timeEnd('wait');

    await page.render('docs/result.pdf');

    await instance.exit();
})();
```

Comment: Have you figured the issue out?